# How do I translate this small passage about make-up, depression, and Alzheimer?

Tags: grammar, translation

Can somebody help me with the translation for

> 実際にうつ病やアルツハイマーの治療として、女性患者に化粧やヘアチェンジを実践することもあるくらいです。お化粧はテンションをあげてくれるお薬でもあるんですね。

I came up with this

> Did you know (or truthfully), as a treatment for depression or Alzheimer's, female patients will practice using make-up or change their hair colour? Cosmetics are a medicine that can heighten your tension

I'm really not sure about the second sentence.

Comment: It tells cosmetics and changing hair style can be a cure for depression and Alzheimer. The style of these sentences is casual not rigorous, so these give me an impression that these are not trustful remedies.

Comment: ヘアチェンジを実践もある is not a correct Japanese. It should be modified as ヘアチェンジを実践する例もある.

Comment: Perhaps one point to keep in mind is that テンション does not translate well to tension. The Japanese word means excitement.

Comment: Thanks so much, noel_lapin. And yes, the text is from definitely not from an academic source. Do you mind explaining to me the difference between ヘアチェンジを実践もある and ヘアチェンジを実践する例もある?
virmaior, thanks for that. I definitely slip up on those katakana with modified (yet genitally related) meanings.

Comment: 「ヘアチェンジを実践もある」is ungrammatical. It should be a typo for ヘアチェンジを実践することもある, 実践する場合もある, or 実践する例もある.

Answer (score 4):

It's parsed as

> [実際に(うつ病やアルツハイマーの治療として)、{(女性患者に)(化粧やヘアチェンジを)実践することもある}]くらいです。

The subject for 実践する(carry out in practice) is not written here but it should be 医者(doctor), 医療機関(medical institution) or 病院(hospital), or maybe 家族(family).

実際に in practice, in fact,
うつ病やアルツハイマーの治療として as a treatment for depression or Alzheimer's,
**病院が hospitals, ← subject** 
女性患者に on female patients,
化粧やヘアチェンジを make-up or change of hair-style ←object 
実践する carry out in practice ← verb 
こともある  There are cases where... ; in some cases  
くらいです。even...

So it literally means:

> In fact, there are even cases where they(=hospitals/doctors) carry out in practice make-up or change of hair-style on their female patients as a treatment for depression or Alzheimer's.

Answer (score 0):

There are several places where I think you're getting the translation wrong (not something I am beyond myself).

> 実際にうつ病やアルツハイマーの治療として、女性患者に化粧やヘアチェンジを実践もあるくらいです。

Did you know (or truthfully), as a treatment for depression or alsheimers, female patients will practice using make-up or change their hair colour? Cosmetics are a medicine that can heighten your tension

実際に = in reality [I'm not sure why you're making it a question]
YのXとして = as an X for Y 
女性患者に = to female patients
化粧やヘアチェンジ = changing their hairstyle or makeup (not necessarily just hair color)
を実践もあるくらいです = also appear to be practical. <-- on this point, you seem to be misunderstanding how 実践 means practice. It doesn't mean 練習 as in doing something, it means practical as in having a practical.

So all of that brought together = In reality, changing hair styles or cosmetics when used as medical treatment, appears to have a practical effect for female patients.

> お化粧はテンションをあげてくれるお薬でもあるんですね

= Cosmetics are a medicine that can raise your spirits, aren't they?

(taking テンションをあげてくれる to mean "can raise your mood/spirits")

---

But noel_lapin suggests, this definitely doesn't sound like academic Japanese. Is this from cancan's sister publication or something?

Comment: Thanks for the break down, virmaior. 
I made it a rhetorical question because I thought it suited the text more. kotobank's definition of 実践 makes me feel like this is more of put in to practice/implementation. 
Thanks for the translation on the second one. I understood what it was saying but I couldn't put it down in words properly.

Comment: could someone explain the downvote?